# How can I avoid blurry text/line rendering in matplotlib animations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, matplotlib, gif

I'm trying to figure out how to make high-quality animations/illustrations in with the `matplotlib.animations` module. So far, however, they tend to have blurry text (sometimes severe, depending on the video size) and often strange artifacts in the conversion of various vector graphics to bitmap. Here's an example made with `ImageMagick`:

[image: Example gif]

You'll notice the square boxes have jagged lines, and while in this example the title fared okay, other times it can be pretty mangled.

What settings can I tweak to make these animations higher-quality?

Comment: Matplotlib doesn't native support gif so the problem is on the Imagemagic side, could you provide your code in order to help you

Comment: This seems to be a simple problem of interpolation to pixels. Providing more pixels would make the image "clearer". To this end you may set the `dpi` to a higher value, like `plt.figure(dpi=300)`.

Answer (score 2):

A few paramters that you should care about:

```
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata={artist:'O'}, bitrate=900) #<-- increase bitrate

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8),dpi=900) # <-- increase dpi
.
.
.
anim.save(SavePath + 'D6666D9600XZ.mov', writer=writer,dpi=900) #<-- increase dpi
```